# Vertical alignment of beams in MusiXTeX

Tags: vertical-alignment, music, musixtex

The beams of the following example are not vertically aligned on the same level/staff lines.

Is there any way to achieve vertical alignment?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}

\begin{music} 
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\setclef1\bass%
\nobarnumbers%
\startextract%
\Notesp%
    \ibu0D0\qb0{.C}%
\enotes\notes%
    \tbbu0\tbu0\qb0C%
    \ibbu0C0\rlap{\qsk\tbbu0}\qb0C%
\enotes\Notesp%
    \tbu0\qb0{.C}%
\enotes\Notes%
    \ibu0D0\qb0C\tbu0\qb0C%
\enotes%
\endextract%
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
  \instrumentnumber{1}\setclef1\bass
  \nobarnumbers
  \startextract
    \Notes
      \ibu0C0\qb0{.C}\tbbu0\tqh0C%
    \en
    \Notes
      \ibu0C0\roff{\tbbu0}%
      \qb0C\tbu0\qb0{.C}%
    \en
    \Notes
      \Dqbu CC%
    \en
  \endextract
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I just changed the spacing commands.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in MusiXTeX. In any case, MusiXTeX is very hard to use and no longer being developed.

You may be able to do this with the PMX preprocessor for MusiXTeX, but I'm not going to learn how to use it just to find out! See section 2.2.11 of the manual pmx276.pdf, for example.

The input to PMX looks more like Lilypond than raw MusiXTeX, so you might as well use lilypond-book instead and get even more control over the notation.

To do this with lilypond-book, give your input file the extension `.lytex` (not `.tex`)

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\begin{lilypond}
{
  \clef "bass" \omit Staff.TimeSignature \relative c,
  {
    c8.[ c16] c16[ c8.] c8[ c8]
  }
}
\end{lilypond}

\end{document}
```

Create the `.tex` file from the `.lytex` with `lilypond-book --pdf foo.lytex`. Then run `pdflatex foo` or however you want to compile `foo.tex`.

Note, the `--pdf` option in `lilypond-book` creates a PDF containing an image of the notation, which is included in the `.tex` file. The image can be in output other formats as well as `.pdf`.

See http://lilypond.org/ for full documentation.

[image]

Comment: The current manual of MusiXTeX says “Revised July 25, 2017” so it is at least still maintained…

Comment: They even post a chagenlog: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/musixtex/doc